# unexpected endpoint behavior in ggplot2::stat_ecdf()

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

I have some data for a gain chart.  (I have percentiles of modeled scores for all the target outcomes.)

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(obs_set = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Training/Validation", 
"Test"), class = "factor"), pctl = c(0.999903481425, 0.99980696285, 
0.999584970127501, 0.999498103410001, 0.999488451552501, 0.999353325547502, 
0.998706651095003, 0.998610132520004, 0.998291621222504, 0.998204754505004, 
0.997615991197506, 0.997577383767506, 0.996284034862509, 0.99615856071501, 
0.99603308656751, 0.995724227127511, 0.995376760257512, 0.995328500970012, 
0.995038945245012, 0.994894167382513, 0.994855559952513, 0.994787996950013, 
0.993957937205015, 0.993948285347515, 0.993600818477516, 0.99185383227002, 
0.991670446977521, 0.990087542347525, 0.989672512475026, 0.98802204484253, 
0.987607014970031, 0.985531865607536, 0.982472226780044, 0.979624928817551, 
0.979219550802552, 0.977183008870057, 0.97584140067756, 0.975407067090062, 
0.975020992790062, 0.974654222205063, 0.965166446282587, 0.965040972135087, 
0.96396961595259, 0.962850000482593, 0.961662822010096, 0.9598579246576, 
0.95200131265262, 0.933730346405166, 0.836372059802909, 0.725665254278186
)), .Names = c("obs_set", "pctl"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

In previous versions of `ggplot2`, I was able to build a gain chart that looked sort of like this:
[image]

but did not have the odd behavior at the endpoints circled in red (with desired behavior in blue)

with the following statement:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
ggplot(data,aes(x = 1-pctl)) + 
  stat_ecdf(aes(x = 1-pctl, col = obs_set), size=1, 
            geom="smooth", fill=NA, pad=FALSE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1), labels=percent,breaks=seq(0,1,.1)) +
  xlab("Percent of file") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1), labels=percent) +
  ylab("Percent of target captured") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=1,yend=1), 
               colour = "gray", linetype="longdash", size=1) +
  ggtitle("Gain from predictive model")+
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position=c(.75,.25)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name='Model Performance',
                      limits=c("Training/Validation","Test","No model"),
                      breaks=c("Training/Validation","Test","No model"),
                      values=c("#6BC04B","tan","grey50"))
```

Did something change?  I'm on ggplot2 version 2.1.0, R version 3.2.4.  I swear a couple months ago this worked fine, but I've recently upgraded.

Comment: "[`stat_ecdf`](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS.md) does a better job of adding padding to -Inf/Inf, and gains an argument `pad` to suppress the padding if not needed [#1467](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1467)" although it doesn't look like pad does anything in your case

Comment: @rawr thanks for that link, there looks like a workaround there.